# UITableViewEditingStyle Problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm setting cells to have UITableViewEditingStyleDelete after the user has clicked on an edit button.

Inside of

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableVieweditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I do

```
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
```

Inside of

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I remove the cell and do

```
[_tableView reloadData];
```

However, whenever I click the red minus button that shows up, the delete button appears for about second, then disappears. If I try to click the minus sign again, I tend to see the error "attempting to set a swipe to delete cell when we already have one....that doesn't seem good"

Does anybody know a solution to this? I've tried solutions that I've seen elsewhere but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you show more (i.e. all) of the code?

Comment: Do not call `reloadData` in `commitEditStyle`. Just tell the table view to remove the one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to disable location updating. As soon as I enter editing mode, I execute

```
        [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

And deletion is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put?:

```
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I didn't have this before, but I added it and it didn't change anything.

My problem is not being able to enter edit mode, it's that the delete button disappears/gets covered up after pressing the minus button.

Comment: Its a little hard to know where your problem is with the code you provided. Maybe you could share more code and I can see what your problem is.

Comment: This is the default and isn't needed if all rows can be edited.

Answer (score 0):

1. have you checked that there's a typo: `tableVieweditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` should be `tableViewEditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` => tableView **E** diting...
2. The table view sends the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` message to the data source. The data source must implement it if it wants to insert or delete a row. It must do two things:
   Send **deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:** or **insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:** to the table view to direct it to adjust its presentation. ***Update the corresponding data-model array by either deleting the referenced item from the array or adding an item to the array.***

from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

In other words:

You're only deleting the cell, but (apparently) not the corresponding row from your data model: 
`[_tableView reloadData];` just reloads the whole table and you didn't show us the code where you actually are removing the cell along with its entry in your data model.

Comment: I know my deleting of cells works. Oddly enough, if I used UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert instead, the cell is properly deleted when I click on the green plus button. (It just doesn't work for delete since the delete button itself disappears/gets covered)

I fixed that type but the problem persists. The method was still being called either way, I have an NSLog that confirms that.